# Formatting data using AWK

Tags: awk

**File Content**

```
662293,211,sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

62871,3506,RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

**AWK command Used**

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}'
```

**Output Obtained**

```
in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

Can you guide me to on how I can use AWK to get the following format in the output

**Expected Output**

```
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

Comment: Awk is not shell. Saying "Query in awk shell script" is like saying "Query in screwdriver hammer tool". Awk and shell are 2 different tools for 2 different purposes. Also, this forum exists for people to search for solutions to problems and a subject like "Query in awk shell script" states nothing about your problem and so is unsearchable - please change the subject to be something about the problem you're asking for help with so others with a similar problem can find it in future.

Answer (score 3):

As @RenaudPacalet already mentioned the main problem with your script was not setting FS, but you additionally were using `printf $i` instead of `printf "%s", $i` and that would fail if your input contained printf formatting chars such as `%s`, and you were using `" "` as the output field separator instead of using/print OFS. Here's how to write your code correctly using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=3; i<NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print $NF}' file
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')
RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

but more idiomatically printing a set of values in a loop is written as:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')
RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

so you don't have to specify the printf formatting string twice (no big deal in  your case but can be an issue for other formatting strings) - once for everything before NF and then again for NF.

In your case though, the right thing to do if you were using awk is just remove the first 2 comma-separated fields with a regexp:

```
$ awk '{sub(/([^,]*,){2}/,"")} 1' file
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

which would be more appropriate for sed as it's a simple substitution:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^,]*,){2}//' file
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

but in reality, this is a job for cut:

```
$ cut -d, -f3- file
sname in ('Market District', 'Express', 'Market', 'Market District Express')

RTANAME in ('ALLIANCE TA')
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to tell `awk` that the field separator is a comma instead of the default spaces. Moreover, `awk` fields are numbered starting from 1, not 0. So, if you want to skip the 2 first fields, you must start your `for` loop at `i=3`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=3; i<NF; i++) printf "%s," $i; print $NF}'
```

Note that once you told `awk` that the comma is the field separator, `printf $i` will not print the comma any more. This is why, to preserve them, I replaced your:

```
printf $i " "
```

by:

```
printf "%s," $i
```

Another option, if your `awk` supports this (non-POSIX), consists in shifting all fields by two positions, discarding the 2 last ones, and using the comma also as the output separator (`OFS`):

```
awk -F, 'NF>=2{for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++)$i=$(i+2);NF-=2}1' OFS=,
```

But it's probably not easier to understand (the final `1` is a strange awk-ism, it is the same as `{print}`).

Comment: Thank you @Renaud Pacalet, the new AWK statement worked fine and i got the required output

Comment: Never do `printf $i` as that'll fail when the input data contains printf formatting chars, always do `printf "%s", $i` for any input data instead (so ditto for `printf $0` or `printf $NF` or `var=$1; printf var`, etc.).

Comment: Decrementing NF (`NF-=2`) is undefined behavior per POSIX. In some awks it'll remove the last 2 fields, in others it'll be ignored, in yet others it could do anything else. Use it if you like but then be sure to state that caveat and state which awk(s) it'll work in (e.g. it'll do what you want in GNU awk) so people reading this in future don't waste time trying to make it work in their awk which doesn't support it.